# JSTL C:foreach function not displaying all values of returned array

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a servlet that passess an arraylist to the Jsp to be printed. The arraylist contains values of int, string and date types.

I am using JSTL C:Foreach to iterate the arraylist and display the value in the JSP.

Below is the code I have used in my JSP.

```
        <c:forEach var="element" items="${SearchResult}">
        <table>
            <tr>

                    <td>${element.DID}</td>
                <td>${element.DTitle}</td>
                <td>${element.Ddate}</td> 
                <td>${element.PName}</td>
                <td>${element.ISBN}</td>
                <td>${element.LibID}</td> 
                <td>${element.Position}</td>
                <td>${element.Availability}</td> 

            </tr>
        </table>
    </c:forEach>
```

The issue here is, when I run this JSP I get an error saying that the properties Ddate, LibID, Position and Availability are not present in the class file I have written to get those values (But I am using the same names as written in the class file for these attributes).

But however if I just print the ${element} all the values are getting printed.

On a side note, I have written sysout in my java classfile (DAO), servlet and every print result has all the values of the arraylist in them, it just seems to me that JSTL is where the issue is.

What might the issue here be, am really confused. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you post the class that represents an `element` ?

Comment: Lowercase the first letter of all properties. Read Java bean specs.

Comment: Setting the properties to lowercase worked! Thanks a loads